# Kafka Flink logging issue

Tags: flink-streaming

I am working on Kafka Flink integration actually I am done with that integration , I have written a simple word count program in Java using Flink API, when I ran it by java -jar myjarname it worked fine but when I tried to ran it with ./bin/flink run myjarname command it was giving me following error,

NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.isCheckpointingEnabled

The respected jar is there but still it is giving me above error.

Comment: Sounds like a version miss match of Flink... Make sure your cluster version is the same as your version you code your program against.

Comment: Thank you Matthias ,
I am working on standalone mode and added all the related to same.

Comment: Do you use maven? Did you "clean" your project? Do you build Flink from scratch or do you use binaries?